# Read newest csv records with Node

Tags: node.js, csv

I'd like to watch a CSV file and get the newest records since it was changed. I'm running the following shell command to build a very simple csv file and append a new line every second:

`rm test.csv & x=0 && while true; do echo "${x},${x},${x}" >> test.csv; x=$(($x+1)); sleep 1; done`

The following code prints all the records of the file until the first change and then just emits the dashed line, as if it's not re-reading the file:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs'),
    dataFile = __dirname + '/server/data/test.csv',
    csv = require('csv');

var parser = csv.parse({delimiter: ','}, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});

var watcher = fs.watch(dataFile);
watcher.on('change', fileChange);

function fileChange(e, fn){
    if (e) console.error(e)

    fs.createReadStream(dataFile).pipe(parser);
    console.log('-------')
}
```

Shouldn't the `fileChange` function re-read the file on every change? My ultimate plan here is to get both the previous array of lines and the current one and use lodash's `difference` function to return only the differences. If there's better way, I'm open to hear it though.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `fs.createReadStream()` has opened the file and it's not being closed. So on the second event `fs.createReadStream()` fails. No bueno.

Try using `fs.readFile()` instead like this:

```
function fileChange(e, fn){
    if (e) console.error(e)

    fs.readFile(dataFile, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
        console.log('-------')
    });
};
```

See the documentation here: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue by stating the file on change, and reading the difference in size to the stream data:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs'),
    dataFile = __dirname + '/server/data/test.csv',
    readSize = 0,
    csv = require('csv');

var parser = csv.parse();
parser.on('readable', function(data){
    var record;
    while(record = parser.read()){
        console.log(record);
    }
});

var watcher = fs.watch(dataFile);
watcher.on('change', fileChange);

// fires when the watched file changes
function fileChange(e, fn){

    // get these syncronously
    var stats = fs.statSync(dataFile);
    // if it's smaller, wait half a second
    if (stats.size <= readSize) {
        setTimeout(fileChange, 500);
    }
    // read the stream offset 
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(dataFile, {start: readSize, end: stats.size});

    stream.on('data', function(chunk){
        parser.write(chunk.toString());
    });

    readSize = stats.size;
}
```

Any feedback on why this may not work would be appreciated.